# Avoid overlapping bar labels with strip in ggplot2 multiple plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im new to R.

My problem ist how to avoid overlapping of bar labels (`geom_text`) with the strip (see image).

Or is it possible to label only a selected range of values?

[image]

Comment: you can adjust the scale of the y axis to make the plotting area larger so the labels will fit (e.g., ` + ylim(c(0,55000)`). If you want some label to not be displayed, replace the value of the label with `""`.

Comment: It would be easiest to increase your y limit. Use e.g. `scale_y_continious(expand = c(0.1, 0))`. I'm voting to close because you don't have a reproducible example.

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: thanks for all the quick help! scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.1,100)) works great!